# Acumulador dentro de bucle while

Tags: python

Identifico que me hace falta un acumulador para el juego. Este consiste en 2 equipos y un juez. El siguiente es un ejemplo de partida: cada carácter del juez es un tiempo de juego en el que uno de los 2 equipos gana puntos, pero parece ser que deben acumularse los puntos. Miren lo que sale en mi código:

```
1# +Y.X-|
2# WMT*|-
Juez# |*Y+-*|-|Y-X|+|YM-*T+-X-**W-XY
-->Resultado esperado
#≈F≈VV≈≈≈≈VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV≈≈VV
Que pasa pues lo que me arroja el programa es esto
-->Resultado que arroja
≈FVV≈F≈≈≈V≈V≈V≈VF≈FFV≈V≈FFF≈VV
```

Lo que identifico es que vendría a hacer falta un acumulador de puntos para poder marcar quién va ganando en cada ronda (una ronda es un carácter), pero lo intento incorporar al código y no cuela.

```
ArmasV = input("V: ")
ArmasF = input("F: ")
Reloj  = input("Vulnerabiliadades: ")
i=0
x=len(Reloj)
while i < x:
  resultado1 = set(ArmasV) & set(Reloj[i])
  resultado2 = set(ArmasF) & set(Reloj[i])
  i += 1
  if (resultado1 == resultado2):
   print("≈" , end ="")
  else:
    if(resultado1 > resultado2):
     print("V", end ="")
    else:
      if(resultado2 > resultado1):
       print("F", end ="")
```

Comment: No tengo una idea clara de cómo debe trabajar ese algoritmo. Pero, suponiendo que por cada caracter, `c`, de `Reloj`: Si `c` está en `ArmasV` y `ArmasF`, imprime `≈`; si `c` solo está en `ArmasV`, imprime `V`; y si `c` solo está en `ArmasF`, imprime `F`. Si lo anterior es así, entonces la salida es exactamente como la describes, no hay forma de que salga el *Resultado Esperado*. Si el algoritmo es así, entonces se puede escribir el código de una forma mucho más sencilla. Si no, entonces tendrías que explicar cómo debería trabajar.

Comment: Entiendo, entonces debo explicarme mejor, se debe acumular los puntos, me refiero si empatan "≈" seria como sumar un punto a cada uno, pero si gana "V" se le daría un punto  y si gana "F" se le agrega un punto, eso significa que va acumulando puntos y el resultado que debe imprimir es la acumulación de esos puntos no el resultado inmediato que es lo que esta haciendo. Básicamente van  F += 1     /    V += 1 y así debería funcionar el contador, pero como lo dije lo eh intentado y no cuela

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que ya entendí, es el resultado acumulativo de cada comparación.

Por ejemplo, si gana jugador **F** su acumulador `acF` se incrementa en `+1`, pero, *suponiendo*, que jugador **V** tiene en su acumulador, `acV` un `+2`; entonces el resultado seguirá siendo `'V'`.
Solo cambiará a `'F'` cuando `acF` sea mayor que `acV`.

Si esto es así, un código parecido al de @CandidMoe, pero con los ajustes pertinentes:

```
ArmasV = '+Y.X-|' # <- datos de prueba
ArmasF = 'WMT*|-' # <- datos de prueba
Reloj  = '|*Y+-*|-|Y-X|+|YM-*T+-X-**W-XY' # <- datos de prueba

acV = acF = 0 # Acumulador V y acumulador F
res = []
for c in Reloj:
    acV += 1 if (c in ArmasV) else 0
    acF += 1 if (c in ArmasF) else 0
    if acV == acF:
        res.append("≈")
    elif acV > acF:
        res.append("V")
    else:
        res.append("F")
        
print(''.join(res))
```

Esto da como resultado: `≈F≈VV≈≈≈≈VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV≈≈VV`

Comment: Exactamente, era incorporar el acumulador e imprimir, muchas gracias, great

Answer (score 1):

Una versión simplificada del código:

```
match = []
for tic in Reloj:
  resultado1 = tic in ArmasV
  resultado2 = tic in ArmasF
  if (resultado1 == resultado2):
     match.append("≈")
  elif(resultado1 > resultado2):
     match.append("V")
  else:
     match.append("F")
```

No necesitas recorrer por índice las jugadas de la partida; puedes iterar directamente con `for tic in Reloj`.

Cada "tic" es un caracter que debe ser revisado contra ArmasV y ArmasF. Para eso basta simplemente con preguntar `tic in ArmasV`.

Luego de hechas las dos comparaciones, usas un `if-elif-else` para discriminar en que caso estás.

En lugar de imprimir el resultado de cada movida, los guardo en una lista `match` para uso posterior.

**Mejora**

Para revisar el resultado agregare dos listas, `rV` y `rF`,

```
rV = []
rF = []
```

donde guardare el caracter encontrado en cada comparación dentro del ciclo:

```
  resultado1 = tic in ArmasV
  resultado2 = tic in ArmasF
  rV.append(tic if resultado1 else " ")
  rF.append(tic if resultado2 else " ")
```

Asi, al terminar, puedo imprimir los resultados y debajo los caracteres encontrados en cada jugador:

```
print(''.join(match))
print(''.join(rV))
print(''.join(rF))
print("Puntos jugador V: ", len(rV) - rV.count(' '))
print("Puntos jugador F: ", len(rF) - rF.count(' '))
```

El puntaje de cada jugador es el largo de `rV` y `rF` una vez que descuentas los blancos.

#### Demo

```
ArmasV = "+Y.X-|" # input("V: ")
ArmasF = "WMT*|-" # input("F: ")
Reloj  = "|*Y+-*|-|Y-X|+|YM-*T+-X-**W-XY" # input("Vulnerabiliadades: ")
rV = []
rF = []
match = []
for tic in Reloj:
  resultado1 = tic in ArmasV
  resultado2 = tic in ArmasF
  rV.append(tic if resultado1 else " ")
  rF.append(tic if resultado2 else " ")
  if (resultado1 == resultado2):
   match.append("≈")
  elif(resultado1 > resultado2):
     match.append("V")
  else:
     match.append("F")

print(''.join(match))
print(''.join(rV))
print(''.join(rF))
print("Puntos jugador V: ", len(rV) - rV.count(' '))
print("Puntos jugador F: ", len(rF) - rF.count(' '))
```

produce:

```
≈FVV≈F≈≈≈V≈V≈V≈VF≈FFV≈V≈FFF≈VV
| Y+- |-|Y-X|+|Y -  +-X-   -XY
|*  -*|-| - | | M-*T - -**W-  
Puntos jugador V:  22
Puntos jugador F:  20

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Tnk U por el punto de vista